# New Sec-* headers in WebView2

Tags: c++, webview2

Working with MS WebView2 in C++ I can see a number of "Sec-*"-headers if visiting https://manytools.org/http-html-text/http-request-headers/

Example of a few:

```
Sec-Fetch-Dest document
Sec-Fetch-User ?1
Sec-Fetch-Mode navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site none
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile ?0
Sec-Ch-Ua "Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Microsoft Edge";v="100", "Microsoft Edge WebView2";v="100"
```

These new headers are mentioned in https://wicg.github.io/ua-client-hints/

Is there any way to access/edit those headers, preferably in C++?

It's possible to disable the Sec-Ch headers with a command line option:

```
--disable-features=UserAgentClientHint
```

and to do that from C++:

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions> options = Microsoft::WRL::Make<CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions>();
options->put_AdditionalBrowserArguments(L"--disable-features=UserAgentClientHint");
```

However, I want to be able to edit those values.

Further googling revealed this page which I guess answers this post:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name

Comment: do you mean reading/editing those on the client-side before sending them?

Comment: Yes, precisely!

Comment: Those headers get added a little late in the request cycle (in `SetFetchMetadataHeader`). You can not read many of them, but you can overwrite a couple of them in a request callback. (i.e. add `add_WebResourceRequested` after `AddWebResourceRequestedFilter`, then set the header field). Some like `Sec-Fetch-Mode` can be changed there. But others like `Sec-Fetch-Site` get overwritten again.

Comment: Those "forbidden" header fields are forbidden for the client-code like JS. They're not forbidden for user-agents like webview. In fact you can edit the "sec-ch" headers just fine in my test. I'll post the example code in a couple minutes. Also, there's always the option of setting a local proxy server that just edits the header fields and forwards the rest of the request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that the `sec-*` headers are part of the "forbidden header" lists. But they are forbidden for client code like the JS that runs on the user-agent. But user-agents like the browser can set those fields.

You can change some of the `sec-*` headers inside a callback added to `add_WebResourceRequested`. Some fields like `Sec-Fetch-Site` get overwritten afterwards, others like `Sec-Fetch-Mode` can be set, but can't be deleted because they will get a default value, if not set after the WebResourceRequestedEvent. But you can change most of the `sec-ch` ones like this:

**NOTE:** this code is only to demonstrate the approach, it's missing a bunch of error handling

```
EventRegistrationToken webResourceRequestedToken;
webviewWindow->AddWebResourceRequestedFilter(L"*", COREWEBVIEW2_WEB_RESOURCE_CONTEXT_ALL);
webviewWindow->add_WebResourceRequested(
  Callback<ICoreWebView2WebResourceRequestedEventHandler>([](ICoreWebView2* sender,
                                                             ICoreWebView2WebResourceRequestedEventArgs* args) {
    COREWEBVIEW2_WEB_RESOURCE_CONTEXT resourceContext;
    args->get_ResourceContext(&resourceContext);
    ICoreWebView2WebResourceRequest* req = nullptr;
    ICoreWebView2HttpRequestHeaders* headers = nullptr;
    ICoreWebView2HttpHeadersCollectionIterator* iter = nullptr;
    args->get_Request(&req);
    req->get_Headers(&headers);
    headers->GetIterator(&iter);
    BOOL hasCurrent = FALSE;
    iter->get_HasCurrentHeader(&hasCurrent);
    std::vector<std::wstring> headersToDelete;
    std::wstring secChPrefix = L"sec-ch";
    while (hasCurrent) {
      LPWSTR name = nullptr, value = nullptr;
      iter->GetCurrentHeader(&name, &value);
      if (secChPrefix.compare(0, secChPrefix.size(), name, secChPrefix.size()) == 0) {
        headersToDelete.push_back(name);
      }
      iter->MoveNext(&hasCurrent);
    }
    for (auto header : headersToDelete) {
      headers->RemoveHeader(header.c_str());
    }
    // Setting "Sec-Fetch-Site" will have no effect, will get overwritten afterwards
    headers->SetHeader(L"Sec-Fetch-Site", L"same-origin");
    // This will work, but removing this key will just make it take the default value
    headers->SetHeader(L"Sec-Fetch-Mode", L"same-origin");

    return S_OK;
  }).Get(),
  &webResourceRequestedToken);
```

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this tomorrow and get back with the result.